# Can Ubuntu Server 10.04.4 LTS be upgraded to NON-LTS?

Tags: server, upgrade, lts

I have a server running Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS. Can I upgrade this distribution to precise LTS, then from there, convert to non-LTS releases?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> convert to non-LTS releases?

There's no such thing as converting in this context.

The only thing that you want to change here is the awareness level of new releases. One can set this to "supported" (regular) releases, "long term only" (LTS) releases, or even "nothing" (no major upgrades).

The GUI way of setting this op is mentioned [in the answer of Im'juz ChanYun](https://askubuntu.com/a/240181/88802), but for command line, this is changing this file: `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`:

```
# Default behavior for the release upgrader.

[DEFAULT]
# Default prompting behavior, valid options:
#
#  never  - Never check for a new release.
#  normal - Check to see if a new release is available.  If more than one new
#           release is found, the release upgrader will attempt to upgrade to
#           the release that immediately succeeds the currently-running
#           release.
#  lts    - Check to see if a new LTS release is available.  The upgrader
#           will attempt to upgrade to the first LTS release available after
#           the currently-running one.  Note that this option should not be
#           used if the currently-running release is not itself an LTS
#           release, since in that case the upgrader won't be able to
#           determine if a newer release is available.
prompt=lts
```

Once you set this to `prompt=normal` you'll be notified (and allowed in a regular way) to upgrade to a regular release. *Do this only after you've upgraded to 12.04 directly, as it's the fastest upgrade path.* You really want to avoid the path in the first line here:

```
10.04 -> 10.10 -> 11.04 -> 11.10 -> 12.04 -> 12.10 (if you would select normal now)
10.04 ----------------------------> 12.04 -> 12.10 (if you select normal after 12.04)
```

Answer (score 10):

As an add-on. Once you have changed the upgrade target to normal, you can run

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

to prompt the upgrade manager into action.

Answer (score 3):

There is a setting in update manager (or software updater) to notify you about new versions. You can select only LTS (once in two years) or for any new versions (the twice a year version).

Comment: "update manager (or software updater)" - he's likely not to be using a GUI on Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be able to upgrade it straight to 12.04, and then to 12.10 if you wish.  You might be better staying at 12.04 however; it's supported until 2017 (and you still a few years of support left in 10.04 server as well).