# Upgrading Ubuntu from LTS to newer version, in steps or simply release upgrade?

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I am working with Ubuntu servers since some month, so not too long. I never upgraded an ubuntu version. So right now I am running 12.04 and what I need is 13.04.
I once hear that I should first upgrade to 12.10 and than to 13.04 (for me that doesn't make too much sense, but I am not sure).

When I run `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` Ubuntu wants to install 14.04.  As far as I know 13.04 is now the stable version. How to achieve the step by step upgrading? Even though it's not the best way, I want to try it out on my virtual machine.

Comment: You won’t be able to upgrade directly from 12.04 LTS to 13.04 (unless you reinstall the OS). You will have to first upgrade to 12.10, then upgrade to 13.04.  I think the reason you get 14.04, is because its the next LTS version.

Comment: ah ok, so ubuntu always trys to go to the next lts version? but isn't 13.04 a lts version as well ? and can you tell me how to upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 to 13.04 ?

Comment: No 13.04 is not an LTS version.

Comment: thanks mitch. so every 2 years a new lts? or whats the rule ?

Comment: Yes I believe it every 2 years, ans its supported for 5 years.

Comment: This is a day i learned something :) i am upgrading to 14.04 right now.

Comment: @Private Do not use a development release on a server... Its recommended that if you need something more recent you upgrade to a non LTS or wait until the next LTS is released.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you get 14.04 as an upgrade option is because you are running an LTS version at the moment and the next LTS release is 14.04, and you are only having that possibility because  you are using the `-d` flag (development).

You should not upgrade your servers to a under development version.

To enable release upgrades from a LTS you need to tell the upgrade tool that you are ok if the next upgrade is a non LTS.

You need to change the [option on the configuration file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240160/can-ubuntu-server-10-04-4-lts-be-upgraded-to-non-lts) from LTS to normal and then run the upgrade tool without the `-d` option to upgrade your server to the next non LTS release.