# Can i get my Ubuntu updated from 18.04 to latest version? If so, How can I do that?

Tags: 18.04

While I check for update, it doesnot show any update.

Comment: I'm testing 19.10 upgrades currently, but the only upgrade path I test from is a fully-updated 19.04 system  (LTS releases are tested from the prior LTS or from prior non-LTS release so have extra test).  The only method to skip releases that has any testing is a re-install using 'something-else' and no-format of partitions (ie. replace your system with the new systems). The 'something-else' wipes system directories & attempts to re-install added programs without wiping user directories (if no-format is selected).  Many blogs will tell you how to perform it using *Debian* & *untested* methods

Comment: I'd rather recommend staying on a LTS version, but you can upgrade to 19.10 following those instructions: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-18-10-to-ubuntu-19-04 (Command line method only) As you might not be on a distant machine, skip the ssh configuration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Ubuntu Server 10.04.4 LTS be upgraded to NON-LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240160/can-ubuntu-server-10-04-4-lts-be-upgraded-to-non-lts) You should be able to do this upgrade if you accept "normal" releases as [Henning Kockerbeck describes](https://askubuntu.com/a/1179951) or by editing `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` as in [that answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/240189). Note that [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/q/34430) is misleading. See [Why does `do-release-upgrade` skip a version?](https://askubuntu.com/q/719465).

Answer (score 1):

There are two "types" of Ubuntu releases: "Normal" releases are supported for six months after release. Those are released every six months. So basically, the support for one version ends when the next is released.

Then there are the "long term support" releases. That's what the "LTS" in "Ubuntu 18.04 LTS" means. LTS versions are supported for five years (and you can buy even longer support). Every two years, there's a LTS release instead of a "normal" one. The current LTS is 18.04, released in April 2018. The LTS before that was 16.04, released in April 2016, and so on. The next LTS version will be 20.04 and will be released in April 2020.

You can update from a "normal" release to an LTS release and vice versa. So you could, for example, update from Ubuntu 17.10 ("normal" release from October 2017) to 18.04 LTS, and from that to 18.10 ("normal" release from October 2018). But if you don't want to upgrade every six months, it can be a good idea to go from a LTS version to the next, skipping the "normal" versions inbetween.

The current "normal" version is 19.04 from April 2019. 19.10 will be released some time later this month. The current LTS version is, as mentioned above, 18.04, and the next will be 20.04.

You can decide whether Ubuntu should offer you to update to any new release, including "normal" releases, or whether it should offer you LTS versions only. You can change that setting in the software center.