# Is upgrade from new release to LTS (when it becomes available) supported?

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

For example, it looks like I'll need to start with Ubuntu 23.04 to get support for my hardware.  As of this writing this is the non-LTS version, which only has 9 months of support.  Will it be possible to upgrade directly from this version to the corresponding LTS release when it becomes available?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Answer (score 9):

No, you will have to upgrade to 23.10 and then to 24.04 ...

But 23.10 is available for download now, so you can skip 23.04 if you want to.

Answer (score 7):

The previous two answers failed to mention that:

- You can start with a non-LTS and upgrade until your reach an LTS (for example, 23.04 → 23.10 → **24.04**).
- Once you are on an LTS, you can edit the file `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and switch from "`normal`" (= non-LTS) to "`lts`".
- After that, you will only need to upgrade from LTS to LTS (e.g. **24.04** → **26.04** → **28.04** etc).

If you later decide to switch back to the non-LTS schedule, you should wait until the first non-LTS (following immediately an LTS) is released (for example, **24.04** → 24.10) and edit this file back to "`normal`".

More information can be found in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/240189/855322).

Comment: Both of the previous answers explicitly did mention that process.

Comment: how to upgrade from ubuntu 23.10 to ubuntu 24.04. sudo do-release-upgrade shows sudo do-release-upgrade

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu uses a two year *development* cycle for the LTS; the cycle for 24.04 LTS started just after release of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS or the prior LTS.

The development progress can be seen via the 3 non-LTS releases show the progress; ie. 22.10, 23.04 & 23.10, and you can *release-upgrade* to that system from the LTS anytime (ie. 22.04 would have *release-upgraded* to 22.10 after its release, but after it went EOL, the *release-upgrade* moved you to 23.04 which is where it is currently. Once on that cycle however, you need to *release-upgrade* through each release as per Soren's answer.

Your alternative is to remain on 22.04 LTS, and after release of Ubuntu 24.04.1, you will be able to *release-upgrade* from one LTS to the next LTS release.