# Should I install 24.04 now or wait till after April 2024 when it is LTS?

Tags: 22.04, 24.04

I will receive a new Lenovo Thinkpad with Ubuntu 22.04 (current LTS) next week (Mar. 2024). I was thinking of immediately wiping it clean and installing 24.04. By doing that, will I have any problems getting updates after Apr. 2024 when 24.04 officially becomes the LTS version?

I have no concerns about instability in the current release of 24.04 as long as updates after April and into the future are not affected. I also am in no hurry to start using it, so if waiting till after the official April release makes things easiest in the long run, then I would rather wait.

Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I’ve noticed the the terms alpha and beta are used differently in different circumstances. So I found those terms confusing. I didn’t see any mention of “LTS” in that post. I am leaning towards avoiding touching my computer for a month after I get it to avoid future problems.

Comment: Yes. What you want to do should work. The 24.04 you install today will be the generally available (GA) version by the end of April 2024. You don't have to reinstall after the final release.

Comment: However, if the computer is factory installed with Ubuntu 22.04, the installed version may have some special patches to get everything working. The new 24.04 may not have those patches. So everything, such as webcam, Wi-Fi etc. may not work with 24.04.

Comment: Either way, once you've installed a supported Ubuntu release, you should keep up with software updates, at least weekly, or even by setting up unattended-upgrades.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone’s comments, especially 'user68186' for the good pointer: my laptop's factory-installed Ubuntu will include drivers set up to work with my hardware. So perhaps it is best to find a way to UPGRADE 22.04 to 24.04 rather than wiping it clean and starting over.

It appears user 'FedKad' has addressed my concern explicitly in this post:
[Is upgrade from new release to LTS (when it becomes available) supported?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1490017/is-upgrade-from-new-release-to-lts-when-it-becomes-available-supported)

I'll investigate that route.